# Does list slicing create shallow or deep copy?

Tags: python

```
Lst1 = [1,2,3,4]

Lst2 = Lst1

Lst3 = Lst1[0:2]

Lst4 = Lst1[:]
```

So Lst1 and Lst2 point to same list.

And Lst3 points to slice of Lst1.

And Lst4 point to slice of Lst1.

Whether Lst3 & Lst4 (output of slicing) are deep or shallow copy?

Comment: The `Lst3` assignment actually creates a new list, not a reference to `Lst1`.  There isn't any such thing as a "slice of a list" object; the slice operator simply returns a new list.

Comment: Hence the use of `copied_list = original_list[:]` to make shallow copies - from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "shallow copy"?

Comment: **no**. Assignment **never copies at all in Python**. This is *crucial to understand*

Comment: A *full slice* produces a shallow copy, e.g. `result = my_list[:]` but something other than a full slice isn't really a *copy*.

Comment: So list slicing like my_list[1:3] returns new list. But what kind is it - shallow or deep?

Answer (score 3):

No, they're very different. The first one isn't doing any copying at all.

```
Lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
Lst2 = Lst1
Lst3 = Lst1[0:2]
```

To see the difference, let's add a few lines below

```
Lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
Lst2 = Lst1
Lst3 = Lst1[0:2]

Lst3[0] = 999
print(Lst1) # Still [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(Lst3) # [999, 2]

Lst2[0] = 998
print(Lst1) # [998, 2, 3, 4]
print(Lst2) # [998, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now, there are some external tools in Python that do it differently. For example, [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) will create *views* back to the original array when you take a slice.

```
import numpy as np

Lst1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
Lst2 = Lst1
Lst3 = Lst1[0:2]

Lst3[0] = 999
print(Lst1) # [999, 2, 3, 4]
print(Lst3) # [999, 2]

Lst2[0] = 998
print(Lst1) # [998, 2, 3, 4]
print(Lst2) # [998, 2, 3, 4]
```

But that's an external library. Built-in Python lists will create copies of lists when you use the `:` slice notation.

Comment: So slicing creates a new List, but is it a shallow or deep copy of the original list?

Comment: @variable It's shallow. Nothing in Python implicitly deep-copies, except the aptly-named `copy.deepcopy` Any mutable data structures *inside* the list will not be copied and will simply be referenced in the new list.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not any kind of copy.

Shallow copy is relevant when your list elements are mutable: You get a new list, which could be modified without affecting the original list (e.g. appending a new element, setting an element, etc.), but each element points to the same respective element which the original list points to.

Examples (changes list elements to be sets, so they're mutable):

Assignment:

```
Lst1 = [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}]
Lst2 = Lst1
Lst1[1] = 'aaa'

print(Lst1) # [{1}, 'aaa', {3}, {4}]
print(Lst2) # [{1}, 'aaa', {3}, {4}]
```

Shallow copy:

```
Lst1 = [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}]
Lst2 = Lst1[:]
Lst1[1] = 'aaa'

print(Lst1) # [{1}, 'aaa', {3}, {4}]
print(Lst2) # [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}]

Lst2[0].add(999)

print(Lst1) # [{1, 999}, 'aaa', {3}, {4}]
print(Lst2) # [{1, 999}, {2}, {3}, {4}]
```

And, for the sake of completion, Deep Copy*:
*well, 1 level deep...*

```
Lst1 = [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}]
Lst2 = [x.copy() for x in Lst1]
Lst1[1] = 'aaa'
Lst2[0].add(999)

print(Lst1) # [{1}, 'aaa', {3}, {4}]
print(Lst2) # [{1, 999}, {2}, {3}, {4}]
```

Comment: Could you please add an example showing how the behaviour will be when slicing is made as such -> Lst2 = Lst1[1:4] #is this an assignment/shallow copy/deep copy/or what?